# Circuit for DC / DC transistor voltage booster doesn’t work

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am trying to recreate [this voltage booster circuit,](https://circuits-diy.com/simple-voltage-booster-circuit-using-transistors-diy/) but the initial voltage is not boosted. It stays the same. According to that scheme, the voltage should be boosted to at least 40V but in my case it stays 1.5V.

Here is the scheme I used. Can someone please check what is wrong with it and why the voltage is not boosted?

I tried lowering the values of all resistors by half and removing the Zener diode, but the output voltage is always 1.5.

Here are the datasheets for the transistors:

[BC557](https://components101.com/asset/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/BC557%20Datasheet.pdf)

[2N3904](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NXP%20PDFs/2N3904.pdf)

Here is the circuit I used:

[image]

Comment: What if the problem is not in the schematis? We have no way to know if you built that circuit correctly or used wrong parts. You should add maybe a photo or something.

Comment: Do you have a load attached while testing?

Comment: Also, in my experience, the NPN and PNP transistor don't matter much. You can use almost any NPN or PNP as long as their beta is more than 100. What **can** make or break this circuit is the **inductor**. The energy used to make a high output voltage is stored in the inductor. If you use an inductor which saturates at a low current and/or has a high series resistance, then the circuit will work poorly.

Comment: Also, in this circuit as shown, the output voltage has no **smoothing capacitor** so the output voltage will consist of **pulses**. Depending on what meter you use to measure the output voltage you might get a **wrong reading** due to the pulsed output voltage. The fact that the author of the article you linked doesn't mention this and the fact that he doesn't suggest adding a smoothing capacitor tells you something about the skill level of this guy.

Comment: Does it start switching at all? Is the inductor saturating?

Comment: @winny There is 1.3 - 1.5V output at the end of the circuit no matter if I add or remove any coil. I tried a self made coil for 200uH (25 turns of a 60cm AWG 20 wire over a ferite core)and a couple store bought for unnown values but the output is always 1.3 - 1.5V. 

@ Bimpelrekkie I added a capacitor at the end but this made no difference. 

@ Justme I checked many times and everything is connected as the circuit shows.

Comment: Is the circuit actually oscillating? What's the waveform on T2's collector look like? (also, it really should be Q2...)

Comment: What’s the saturation current of the inductor?

Comment: Take a picture. Please! Also, 1N4148 diode should be a Schottky diode. Furthermore, Remove the inductor and measure the resistance. High resistance might prevent startup or oscillation. Tell us what the resistance measures.

Comment: We really need to know what kind of load your circuit is trying to start up into.  Can you try a 3v white LED as a load? Also, the 2N3904 is only rated for 200mA -- you need a better power transistor. Try a 2N4401.